# Is it possible to refer to the value of a const field in C# XML documentation?

Tags: c#

I want to include in the documentation that the algorithm changes to a faster but more memory consuming version of itself if one of the arguments exceeds a constant (that is an arbitrary value I've set based on benchmarking how the code runs on my PC in Debug mode. It can and probably will change in the future).

TL;DR: Is it possible to do something like this in a C# XML comment?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private const int _LIMIT = 2 << 24;

    /// <summary>
    /// If <paramref name="arg"/> exceeds the value ‭of <some_tag>_LIMIT</some_tag> something different happens
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arg"></param>
    public void DoWork(int arg)
    {
        //work
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `<see>`, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the current language specification, it is not possible. What is required to achieve this? The following language features:

1. Constant expressions - for manipulating compile-time constants at compile time.
2. XML docs constant expression support.

While the first one is actively discussed in several issues in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues repository the second feature seems missing from proposals and discussions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little bit of a hack but maybe you can use it :

Set your const summary to the const value.

```
/// <summary>
/// "defaultString"
/// </summary>
private const string docTest = "defaultString";
```

Then inherit it's documentation.

```
/// <summary>
/// blah blah,  default = <inheritdoc cref="docTest"/> 
/// </summary>
public string DocTest { get; set; } = docTest;
```